Rails/Redis ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error even when the record clearly exists
I am currently working on a piece of software for the company I am working at, and I am at a complete loss as to how I can resolve this error.
This is what Sidekiq spits back at me
09:26:23 sidekiq.1 | 2024-07-02T13:26:22.990Z pid=45032 tid=17cw WARN: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Quote with 'id'=1758

I can't share too much code, but below should be enough
class CreateOrUpdateApiJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  # Called with quote=1758 and action=create
  def perform(quote, action)

     Quote.find(quote)
     if action == "create"
          ApiService.create()
     elsif action === "update"
          ApiService.update()
     end
  end
end

# This is queued with
CreateOrUpdateApiJob.perform_later(quote, "create")

What I am working with:

MacBook Pro 2015, 2.8 Ghz Quad Intel Core i7, 16GB of 1600MHz DDR3, 1TB SSD, AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2GB, macOS Monterey 12.7.5

Ruby 3.1.4, via rbenv

PostgreSQL v15 server

Gems

Rails 6.1.7.4

Sidekiq 7.1.2

ActiveRecord 6.1.7.4

redis 4.8.1, redis-client 0.15.0

pg 1.5.4




The commands I run (via the foreman gem):
bundle exec rails server -p 3000 -e production
redis-server # Omitted in production, we have a separate Redis for production
bundle exec sidekiq -c 2 -q default -q mailers

I have tried just about everything. Whether it be passing the whole record into the quote argument, sending the record as a string and parsing, installing Redis fresh, it just doesn't work.

That is a typo. Thanks for pointing that out!

Have you confirmed that sidekiq is configured to point to the proper database?

if you put a debugger statement before the line Quote.find(quote) you can probe around. Presumably you can find the find statement and receive back "not found". Can you do Quote.count to confirm that you're looking at the db/table you should be? It looks as if the problem is not sidekiq... it's just reporting an ActiveRecord error msg.

Try booting sidekiq in production in your procfile : sidekiq_1: bundle exec sidekiq -e production just to make sure it queries the production dataabse

On a side note using "Or" in a class name reeks to the high heavens. This should be two different classes.
